# Server Socket cannot accepts client. (C# UWP Async Socket Programming)

Tags: server, uwp

i made a Async Server Socket Code using C# Socket.

Although i wrote a code, then test to Console Environment,

it was working, but i tested that code at UWP.

but, it was not working. cannot accepts client.

Bind, Listen, Accept there are all no error, but this socket code cannot accepts client!

how can i solve me?? please help me..

```
    private Socket m_ServerSocket;
    private List<Socket> m_ClientSocket;

    private int m_iPort = 1123;
    private int m_iClients = 8;
    private int m_iBufferSize = 128;

public bool Open(int IN_iPort, int IN_iClients, int IN_iBufferSize)
    {
        try
        {
            m_iPort = IN_iPort;
            m_iClients = IN_iClients;
            m_iBufferSize = IN_iBufferSize;

            m_ClientSocket = new List<Socket>();

            m_ServerSocket = new Socket(
                                AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                SocketType.Stream,
                                ProtocolType.Tcp);

            IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, m_iPort);
            m_ServerSocket.Bind(ipep);
            m_ServerSocket.Listen(m_iClients);

            SocketAsyncEventArgs args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            args.Completed
                += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(Accept_Completed);
            m_ServerSocket.AcceptAsync(args);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }

        m_bIsOpen = true;
        return true;
    }

    private void Accept_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        Socket ClientSocket = e.AcceptSocket;
        m_ClientSocket.Add(ClientSocket);

        if (m_ClientSocket != null)
        {
            SocketAsyncEventArgs args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            byte[] szData = new byte[m_iBufferSize];
            args.SetBuffer(szData, 0, m_iBufferSize);
            args.UserToken = m_ClientSocket;
            args.Completed
                += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(Receive_Completed);
            ClientSocket.ReceiveAsync(args);
        }

        e.AcceptSocket = null;
        m_ServerSocket.AcceptAsync(e);
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked `Internet(Clent&Server)` option in uwp package manifest?

Comment: ok, now i checked it. i missed that. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have check your code, there seems no issue existing in your code. Please check if you have checked [`Internet(Clent&Server)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets)option in your project `appxmanifest`. For more detail you could refer to [Sockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets) official documentation.